# Why do we need RedirectAttributes.addAttribute()?

Tags: spring-mvc

Spring provides the following option to pass attributes(params) to the redirect page by using RedirectAttributes.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class RedirectController {

    @GetMapping("/redirectWithRedirectView")
    public ModelAndView redirectWithUsingRedirectView(RedirectAttributes attributes) {
        attributes.addAttribute("attribute", "redirectWithRedirectView");
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:redirectedUrl");
    }
}
```

The same can be achieved even if we simply append attribute to redirect URL, like the following

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class RedirectController {

    @GetMapping("/redirectWithRedirectView")
    public ModelAndView redirectWithUsingRedirectView() {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:redirectedUrl?attribute=redirectWithRedirectView");
    }
}
```

Both do the same job. Do we get any benefits in terms of memory if we use RedirectAttributes? I am guessing, in the second case, we would be constructing separate ModelAndView object if the attribute value changes for each request.

Comment: They transform the attributes to string for you, encode them for you, append them to the query string for you, and also allow storing flash attributes.